# call a function on an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I need to call a function on a DOM element automatically. The following code works, but I wonder if there's a better way.

```
$('#toc > ul > li').first().find('a').each(loadTopic);
```

My selectors will return exactly one element, so running "each" seems hackish. Is there a better way to call 'loadTopic' on my anchor element?

Comment: It really depends on your HTML layout, but this isn't really the place for this type of question. [Try over here instead](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: with all respect, I don't think it should depend on my layout. The bottom line is that I want to select an element and call a function, not bound to any event (click, etc.). My selectors work. I just wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: My point was simply, according to your HTML, there may be a better way to get the selection, however, as it stands, i really see no better way except maybe to shorten it with something like: `$('#toc > ul > li:first a').each(loadTopic);`. The `:first` is same as `.first()` and then the a tag after of course is same as `.find('a')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.each` is about as good as it gets here, not least because it automatically passes the native DOM elements from within the jQuery object, and not wrapped up as jQuery objects themselves.  Heck, it even sets `this` to be that element for you.

You could implement a `.call()` plugin that only works on the first element in a jQuery object, but it would be kinda pointless...

Answer (score 0):

Create simple jquery plugin and call `$('#toc > ul > li').first().find('a').myPlugin();`

Comment: not a good answer - any well behaving plugin will internally call `.each` anyway...

Comment: If you have one element, each will not be used, but my solution is a little better